# Divide symfony app for different domains

Tags: php, symfony, web

I would know, does it is possible to *divide* Symfony 4 application for 2 domains. I would see it as :

> routes.yaml

```
index:
    path: domain1.com/
    controller: App\Controller\ServiceController::indexAction

results:
    path: domain1.com/results
    controller: App\Controller\ServiceController::resultsAction

admin:
    path: domain2.com/admin
    controller: App\Controller\AdminController::indexAction
```

I would limit routes for domain1 and others available only from domain2.
I know I can just part my app for 2 new, I can try with apache hosts config, but I think easiest and fastest is my idea. Ah. I don't speak about subdomains.

Comment: Don't think it can be done via the `routes.yaml` file. I had to do it once, what I did was sure the DB to store the different domains, store the found domain into session varaible, and use it to handle the choice of routes

Comment: @kunic wrote correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `host` to your route, you can read more [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html)